# ImportError: No module named pytesseract on Jupiter lab and VSCode but not my local

Tags: import, importerror, python-tesseract

I have tried running a `ProcessImage.py` file in which I import the package `pytesseract` in Jupiter Lab and VSCode. 
This is the error that pops out :

```
import pytesseract
ImportError: No module named pytesseract
```

I already know that pytesseract is installed in my environment because with `conda list`:

```
pytesseract               0.3.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest                    5.3.5                    py38_0    coda-forge
```

However, if I run my `ProcessImage.py` file on my local no error is prompted.

I know the error is related to paths in Jupiter Lab and VsCode but I can't seem to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to launch your python file using Ctrl+F5 command for run?

I had this same ImportError when trying to launch my python program using the .run extension. It persistently started python 2.7 while my environment was using Python3. I first thought that it was a VS code error but it wasn't.